# What's the definition of "process name" in windows programming?

Tags: windows, process

I am learning to use certain windows APIs regarding to windows handle and proces PIDs. when trying to use GetProcessesByName(), I am confused by the definition of process name. is process name exactly the name of the executable file without the extention?

ex. 
executable name : process name
chrome.exe      : chrome
user32.dll      : user32

is my assumption correct?

Comment: For .NET [`GetProcessesByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9), there's nothing to assume. It's documented that this is a 'friendly name', which is the executable name without the extension. A DLL is not a process name.

Comment: FYI, .NET is not the Windows API. It's a higher-level API that wraps the Windows API when implemented on Windows. However, [.NET core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) is cross-platform. For example, see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/3637) about improving the performance of `GetProcessesByName` in Linux.

Comment: thank you very much. Now I get it.